# MVC 4 Resource file issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, resources

I'm having a weird problem with a resource file. I have some code in a data annotation that will allow some special characters to be used to a username, this part of the code is working fine. In the resource file, I have the UserNameFormatError message that looks like this:

Minimum of 6 letters, numbers, and special characters, no spaces. Special characters include: !,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),-,_,+,.,',`,~,/,=,?,{,},|

The problem I'm having is that when I debug the program, it thinks I'm trying to convert the username to an int. When I take out the "Special characters include: !,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),-,_,+,.,',`,~,/,=,?,{,},|" part of the resource file the code runs fine. Do I have to use some sort of escape for the special character part? Example: if I'm using @ as a special character, do I need to escape this using "\" or the %xx method?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Resource files need to have the "{" and "}" escaped by formatting the string as such: Special characters include: !,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),-,_,+,.,',`,~,/,=,?,{{,}},|

The curly brackets need to be escaped using a double bracket. After modifying this and re-running the program, everything is working fine.